# Vertically aligning two elements

Tags: css, flexbox

```
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</header>
```

I need to vertically align h1 and h2 inside the header. The h2 needs to be below the h1. Is there a way to do this with flex without wrapping the h1 and h2 tags?

---

EDIT

Just to be clear - H1 and H2 should be vertically aligned inside header. H1 and H2 should sit one below the other.

Comment: indeed `h2` will actually *be* below `h1`. What was the question?

Comment: It's usually done using a play with `line-height` but a working example (plnkr/jsfillde) would help

Comment: The question is - how can I vertically align both h1 and h2?

Comment: you mean vertically align the text inside h1 & h2?

Comment: is it ok if change html ? if we add one more element to wrap headers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want

```
<style>
header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
h1,h2{
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</header>
```

Comment: `margin:0;` add it to h1 and h2 so they will be exact center

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with flexboxes like this.

```css
header{
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1,h2{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  background: red;
}

h2{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
</header>
```